# Typescript null chain and type narrowing

Tags: typescript, type-narrowing

I've came across a case where I feel like typescript is not correctly narrowing given type.

```
(value: number[] | null) => {
  if ((value?.length ?? 0) > 0) value[0];
};
```

In the `if` branch it still gives me a `Object is possibly 'null'` even though the condition will not be true if the `value` is `null`.

Shouldn't this be narrowed and why yes/no?

Is there a convenient workaround if this is expected behaviour?

Comment: Because of precedence you need to wrap `value?.length ?? 0` in parentheses. It won't solve the original problem but at least it would fix the logical bug.

Comment: Btw, `value !== null && value.length > 0` condition would work and looks easier to read isn't it.

Comment: @zerkms well that's what null chain operators are for to omit null checks aren't they? But yeah I can agree that the `?? 0` is making it a bit less readable.

Comment: "that's what null chain operators are for to omit null checks aren't they" --- indeed, but only in cases when you can tolerate "null" values returned, and you cannot, since you need to compare it with `> 0`. I understand it's a matter of taste, but I personally would never approve `(value?.length ?? 0) > 0` in a PR.

Comment: I still agree though that the TS _should_ infer it right here, and possibly there is a chance it's a bug or imperfection in its inference implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the full answer but:

This happened because you don't have a direct check for null/undefined and TS is not yet that smart to identify this himself.

You have to options:

**1. More verbose but safer:**

Use check like here:

```js
(value: number[] | null) => {
    if (value ==null && value.length > 0) value[0];
};
```

or with typeguards like here:

```js
(value: number[] | null) => {
    if (!isnull(value) && value.length > 0) value[0];
};

function isnull(value: any): value is null {
    return value == null;
}
```

**2. Option for the sure people:**

Say TS that: *I am sure* just do that and use ! notation. Like here:

```js
(value: number[] | null) => {
  if (value?.length ?? 0 > 0) value![0];
};
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The first option is not any safer then the second one. If the condition passes the `value` must be non-null and non-empty just the linter doesn't see that because of no direct null check that you mentioned at the beginning.

Comment: @MarošBeťko Agree for the current case. But imagine, that someone will change check in the second case. Because of the ! sign, linter may still thought that everything is ok, however, logic maybe already broken. That's why I say, that explicit check is safer